# 2013 Ford Fiesta - Climate Control Problems

Tags: ford, fiesta, climate-control

I've got a problem with a 2013 Ford Fiesta's climate control. The choices between the system are you freeze or roast.

The system is the standard Ford one - options: "Lo" - 15.5-29.5 celsius - "Hi".

There's nothing coming up under diagnostic codes and I've had a friend check the pumps, refrigerant etc. but as he's a mobile guy there's a limit to how much he can diagnose without taking it apart.

The problem is - that under "Lo" it comes out at 8°C from the Air-Con - which is as expected. Everything from 15.5 up to "Hi" comes out as 35°C and when set to automatic, it never turns itself off.

I'm assuming there's a faulty sensor somewhere in the car - is this something that can be resolved with a bit of DIY or would this need to be resolved by a professional garage?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Has it worked properly until recently? Was there a specific event when it started happening? Does it work as it should if you adjust it manually?

Comment: To calirfy, codes in the HVAC module or in the PCM?